# Can I hot deploy Meteor client HTML files?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Meteor is pretty amazing in that you can update the HTML files manually while developing locally and those changes take affect immediately when you save the file.  I would like to take that same functionality and bring it to our deployed environment.  The reason being that we would like to allow our client to make changes to the UI without having to redeploy the application or even know it's a Meteor app.  They might add new fields to a list view, new fields to a form, change labels, etc.

Thus far, I've created a means for them to call a REST service using a DSL to describe those changes and save it in Mongo. Then we have an engine that will dynamically create the HTML templates to implement it.  That all works great.

Next, I'm attempting to do a hot deploy of Meteor HTML files based off a subscription I have with the Meteor DB which stores things that could change on demand.  Is it possible to update the Meteor client filesystem on the fly so I can achieve a hot deploy?

Doing the following on the server publish method results in an `ENOENT: no such directory` error:

```
var result = decodeHTML(cheerio.html());
console.log(result);

// Output to file
fs.writeFile('../client/app/client/templates/request-base-template.html', result, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error: " + err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("File saved successfully");
    }
});
```

Comment: what is '/client/view/template.html'? Do you expect to overwrite your template?

Comment: In production environment you don't even have html files, they are all compiled to JS code that generates that reactive HTML, that you see on the page

Comment: I've updated the path to match what's really there, but yes, you're right they're compiled into JS so this approach is flawed.  So I guess my real question is can I recompile them based off some new updates to the HTML that we store in the MongoDB?

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve. Yes, you can dynamically compile templates based on the changes to HTML, but this sounds like not the best design. If you describe your usecase in more details, there might be a better solution purely based on the model changes? (not on the views)

Comment: Check out a more descriptive problem statement and use case in the updated question above.  I think this would be a really compelling use case to drive more Meteor adoption at our work if this can be accomplished.

Comment: see the answer. Thanks for the extensive description, I like your usecase. I wonder what users are expected to type in html though O_o

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saving files to disk to expect "Hot code push reloads" is definitely a wrong way to go here.

Meteor provides file-watching in the development mode, and it will recompile your whole app and refresh the page in your browser, but this is made for the developer convenience and not for the run-time use by your application. In fact, file-watching is not even shipped when deployed in production.

But here is a way to implement your use-case. It would require some deeper understanding of what Meteor is doing behind the scenes for you.

First of all, you need to realize that Meteor compiles your templates (Spacebars templates) to its own JS DSL (HTMLJS) in the build time. Similar things happen to every structure-based templating, either you compile them in run-time or in build-time. Meteor does it in build-time to make things more efficient. You can read more about it in [Meteor Manual, Blaze chapter](http://manual.meteor.com/#blaze);

The high-level point here is: if you have a template

```
<template name="bla">
  Hello {{name}}!
</template>
```

.. it would be compiled to something like this:

```
Template.__define__("bla", (function() {
  var view = this;
  return [ "Hello ", Blaze.View(function() {
    return Spacebars.mustache(view.lookup("name"));
  }), "!" ];
}));
```

Got it? Great.

Now, you need to get this kind of templates from users and compile them into this JS-based DSL. You can do it with the built-in `spacebars-compiler` package.

```
// on the server!
Meteor.startup(function () {
  // imagine your template is actually coming from database or where you store your user-generated content
  var template = "<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>";
  console.log(SpacebarsCompiler.compile(template));
});
```

If you add `spacebars-compiler` to your app and run this, it will print a nice compiled template. Here is a live demo: http://meteorpad.com/pad/4tHHAvjpcBQwLuN4K

Perfect, now ship this compiled template to the client in any form you want (through database, through a Meteor method or a REST API, it doesn't matter, just get the string to the client).

Once it is there, you can attach it anywhere you want!

One of the easier ways to do it is to register the template in JS code:

```
// on the client! pretend you got the compiledTemplate string from the server
var compiledTemplate = '(function() { var view = this; return HTML.P("Hello ", Blaze.View(function() {return Spacebars.mustache(view.lookup("name")); }), "!");})';
Template.__define__("myAwesomeTemplate", eval(compiledTemplate));
```

And then use things like `UI.dynamic` to render it on the page. You can see a live demo here: http://meteorpad.com/pad/LQJuoooBQjSdJenfW

Comment: I am working on the last example, but my machine got stuck w/o good internet. I will append the rest later

Comment: Neat tricks Slava.  Thanks. 

Make sure to watch for code injection possibilities if you use eval.

Comment: Thanks Slava! Most of this works as you describe but my app is non-trivial in that I have a main index.html that already has a body, etc. and the sub templates I use for different pages. Basically, I just want to put that compiled code into the corresponding HTML page.  If I do this: `{{> UI.dynamic template="srcTemplate"}}` I get an exception on Meteor startup that I have bad formatting in my HTML.

Comment: This is separate, you define a helper that returns the string. That's about it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but it significantly changes my original model of just creating the whole template for a particular system. I'll have to break it into discrete helpers for each piece. Certainly worth it still, given the benefit of dynamic templates!

Answer (score 1):

Would you agree that you are writing a customized cms system?  If so, there are already a few cms systems in meteor.

I found it easy to extend an earlier version of http://azimuthc.ms/

They basically had your needs in mind when they wrote this.

(I am not connected to this project)

Comment: Sort of, but with very tight controls around the content. In other words, we are defining the content to layout a very specific way with certain pages, tabs, etc.  The thing we allow the end user to do is alter what goes on those tabs/containers using predefined styles. Nonetheless, this is still intriguing to see someone is doing something like this.