# HTML from MongoDB into Template

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor

I have a Mongo Collection that contains documents like:

```
{
      "header": "<h2>Header 2</h2>",
      "body": "<p>A paragraph.</p>",
      "subheader": "<h2>What is the ‘fish’?</h2>",
      "paragraph": "<p>A fish is a fish.</p>",
      "paragraph2": "<p>Fish like to swim.</p>"
    }
```

I'd like to be able to grab a document by ID or other arbitrary field and populate a template with it.

Current Handlebars:

```
<template name="panel">
    {{{header}}}
</template>
```

And JS:

In template.body.helpers:

```
panels: function() {
      return Panels.find({});
    }
```

No errors, but nothing int he template.

We have a collection, we have subscribed to it, and the server is publishing it.

I understand that this is not a great solution as we have to hard code the link between the template and the document in Mongo, but for now it'll do. Unless there is a cleaner way of grabbing html from Mongo and using it to populate a template?

Thanks.

EDIT: I made a bad typo! My bad. So, new error:

Uncaught Error: Expected template or null, found: [object Object] in Spacebars-runtime.js

and

Uncaught Error: Can't render the same View twice in view.js

I'm publishing the collection with:

```
Meteor.publish("panels", function() {
    return Panels.find({});
  });
```

Comment: Perhaps the answer can be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573808/can-i-hot-deploy-meteor-client-html-files/25596607#25596607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want single record as you mentioned, I would do it this way

```
<template name="panel">
{{#with panels}}
{{{header}}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Your question about handlebars - better way to do it is to use SafeString,
check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258324/meteor-js-return-innerhtml-in-helper), I had same trouble some time ago

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. This approach is against everything Meteor is set to do. It's against what any MVC framework is out to do (Meteor is not necessary an MVC framework by the way). It's very simple to create a template and bind data to it from your Mongo collection for each paragraph text. Just start on the Meteor site and you'll see the most basic tutorials covering this. e.g.

```
<template name="main">
    <h2>{{panels.subheader}}</h2>
</template>

Template.main.helpers({
  panels: function() {
    return Panels.find({})
  }
});
```

(Not a complete solution to your question by the way)

Comment: Love the start of that comment! :) Blunt + honest = good. Got it sorted.